# Getting Error no matching function for call to ' '

Tags: c++, pointers, operators, destructor

these are the errors i'm getting from one of my functions and can't seem to find out what's causing it. I'm thinking this line is causing the errors

```
if(this != &gardena){ //shallow copy
```

please help

Compiler Errors:

```
Garden.cpp:59:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘Garden::~Garden()’
Garden.cpp:59:17: note: candidate is:
Garden.h:17:2: note: Garden::~Garden()
Garden.h:17:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
Garden.cpp:59:18: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
Garden.cpp:122:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input


Garden& Garden::operator=(const Garden& gardena){

if(this != &gardena){ //shallow copy

    gmap_width = gardena.gmap_width;
    gmap_length = gardena.gmap_length;

if(gardena.garden != nullptr){
    delete [] garden;
    garden = nullptr;
}

if(gardena.garden != nullptr){ //deep copy
    garden = new char[strlen(gardena.garden)];
    strcpy(garden, gardena.garden);
}else{
    garden = nullptr;
}

return *this;
}

Garden::~Garden(){

if(garden != nullptr){
    delete [] garden;
}
}
```

Comment: Do you have a working copy constructor and destructor?  If so, then your `operator=` can be written much more easily than what you attempted.  Also, please format your code properly -- the braces are all over the place.  I wouldn't be surprised if the issue is that you have a missing brace somewhere.

Comment: FYI, here is the `operator=` if you have a working copy constructor and destructor: `Garden& operator=(Garden g){using std::swap; swap(garden, g.garden); swap(gmap_width, g.gmap_width); swap(gmap_length, g.gmap_length); return *this; }`  No pointers, no allocations, and it all works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `}` before `return *this;` so the compiler can't properly parse your destructor code.  In general, if you have any errors related to brace or parenthesis mismatching, fix those first.  It also helps to use proper indentation so you can match braces visually.